# Dockeried setup for Node and Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I want to run two docker containers: one is node server(**backend**) and other has react js code(**frontend**).

My node contains an API as shown below:

```
app.get('/build', function (req, res) {
    ...
    ...
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log("Listening to PORT 3001");
```

I am using this API in my react code as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {

axios.get('http://localhost:3001/build', { headers: {"x-access-token": this.state.token}
      })
           .then(response => {
              const builds = response.data.message;
              //console.log("builds",builds);
              this.setState({ builds: builds,done: true });
           });
}
```

But when I run 2 different Docker containers, exposing 3001 for **backend** container and exposing 3000 for **frontend** container and access *http://aws-ip:3000* (aws-ip is the public IP of my AWS instance where I am running the two docker containers), the request made is

`http://localhost:3001/build` due to which I am not able to hit the node api of docker container.

What changes should I make in the existing setup so that my react application can fetch the data from node server which is running on the same AWS instance?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean other container is running reactjs? Is it a running a web server that serves the react app? Share the docker compose file.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow his tutorial. 
I think you can achieve that with docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Example: https://dev.to/numtostr/running-react-and-node-js-in-one-shot-with-docker-3o09

and here how I am using

```
version: '3'
services:
    awsService:
        build:
            context: ./awsService
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes:
            - ./awsService/src:/app/src
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
    keymaster:
        build:
            context: ./keymaster
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes: 
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./keymaster:/app
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.1
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
        volumes:
            - ./postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    service:
        build:
            context: ./service
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./service/config:/app/config
            - ./service/src:/app/src
        ports:
            - "3001:3000"
    ui:
        build: 
            context: ./ui
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes: 
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./ui:/app
        ports: 
            - "8081:8080"
```

For future reference, if you have something running on the same port, just bind your local machine port to a different port.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it right, the frontend app accessed in the browser cannot reach your API via `http://localhost:3001`. Instead, your react application should access the API via `http://[ec2-instance-elastic-ip]:3001`. Your react app should store in its code. Your ec2 instance security group should allow incoming traffic via port `3001`.

The above setup is enough to solve the problem.

but here are some additional tips.

- assign an elastic IP to your instance. Otherwise, the public IP address of the instance will change if you stop/start the instance.
- setup a domain name for your API for flexibility, easy to remember, can redeploy anywhere and point the domain name to the new address. (many ways to do this such as setting up a load balancer, set up CloudFront with ec2 origin)
- setup SSL for the better security (many ways to do this such as setting up a load balancer, set up CloudFront with ec2 origin)
- Since your react app is a static website, you can easily set up a static s3 website

Hope this helps.